# Facebook access_tokens? How to post to a users wall?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm a little confused on where to start with facebook intergration.
Currently I've created a javascript login button that granting the correct rights to my app.
What I want to do is be able to post to the users steam but I believe I need an access_token. I managed to get an access token in javascript with the following code

```
FB.login(function(response) {
  if (response.authResponse) {
    alert(response.authResponse.accessToken);
  } else {
    alert('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
  }
});
```

Do I need to find a way to store this access token to my database so I can use it whenever I require to post to the users wall?
Also is this the best way to go about getting an access token? I'd rather get it server-side than client-side then passing it to the server.

Sorry if I'm missing something. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to store the access token. It will expire when the user logs out of Facebook. 
To post to a users feed, you use the graph api. Quite simply, you send form data to a special URL.

Yu can see how it works here using the Facebook javascript test console. 
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/console/

You can review the code and see how it works and how to make the graph api do your bidding.

And as for the access token. you send it as a form field called "access_token" your data can be set by either GET or POST.

Comment: What's the best way of getting the access token?

Comment: depends on what your app does. Both the javascript API and PHP api work great, in my experience. The "best" solution is determined by user experience and what the programming requirements are.

Comment: Thanks, I've just looked at the php api and it's really easy. I'm sorry for such a stupid question I'm still trying to get my head around how it works.